# How do I help my branded Uruk captain bully Uruk soldiers into joining him?

Tags: middle-earth-shadow-of-mordor

I've started a mission to help my branded Uruk captain bully Uruk soldiers into joining him. The mission was situated inside an Uruk stronghold, so there were a lot of enemies around. I've killed or branded dozens of enemy Uruks alongside my branded captain, but the mission won't finish.

How exactly do I finish missions where I have to help my branded Uruk captain in bullying Uruk soldiers to join him?

Comment: As the answers say, kill the Uruks who are coloured yellow in wraith mode (if your Uruk captain is branded, they will also be marked without wraith mode). I also had this situation occur and it was when I just went in and killed everything, my captain just wandered around after the mission should have ended. I guess he had no one to recruit and so the victory condition wasn't met. As he was branded, I just grabbed him and instructed him to do something else and we went from there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When the uruk captain starts to "bully" other uruks, go into wraith mode (LB on xbox controller IIRK). You will see that some uruks are yellow coloured. Those are your targets.

Kill these yellow marked uruks, and you should complete the task.

Note: The captain will go to other groups to bully them, so follow him.

Note 2: Don't dismiss the possibility of a glitch. The branding could have caused one.

Comment: **Be careful:** When I tried to go into wraith mode, I killed my branded uruk captain by mistake. This is because (at least in this Mac port) Dispatch has the same key (`V`) as Wraith mode. This may not happen if you don't have your branded captain highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

So I was killing his enemies endlessly; all yellow ones and 100 others with Shadow Strike combo + Branding once hit streak was filled (got that rune with 5x hits instead of 8x)

then decided to just leave the area... Recruitment solved.

Stuck in a loop, apparently, due to branding.

Answer (score 0):

Basically those missions are called :

> ### RECRUITMENT MISSIONS
>
> Uruks seek to increase their following by bullying and recruiting other Uruks, which often results in bloodshed. If the Captain survives, he will increase in power.

Basically all you have to do is defend your branded captain Uruk and kill the ones attacking him.

To identify them go into the Wraith World and they will have a **Yellow** tone to them.

There is actually an achievement that might help you understand better the mechanics of the recruitment if you check out [this guide](http://www.gamepur.com/guide/16432-how-get-middle-earth-shadow-mordor-no-power-numbers-trophy-achievement.html).

It will help you with the recruitment missions overall. Just kill the yellow foes and it's done.